# Wrap Serialized Data to a higher level XML tag

Tags: c#, xml

All,

I have a list of objects which I have serialized to an XML document using XmlSerializer.
However I would like to wrap the whole result into two tags:

```
<message>
<!-My Serialized content goes here-->
</message>
```

Do I need to open it as an XML Document and Add a new root element or is there another way of doing it ?

Rgds,
MK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XmlSerializer writes to an XmlWriter. Write the start tag to the writer first, then serialize, and close your message tag at the end.

Example:

```
XmlWriter writer = // Your writer
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DateTime));
writer.WriteStartElement("message");
ser.Serialize(writer,DateTime.Now);
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked except that I had to add writer.Flush() at the end.